# Erro ao 404 ao definir URL Amigável no .htaccess

Tags: php, htaccess

Está dando erro 404 ao acessar a URL Amigável que tentei fazer pelo `.htaccess`: `RewriteRule ^es/guarapari/([0-9]+)/([[a-z0-9-]+)/?$ empresas.php?id=$1&nome=$2 [NC]`

**.htaccess completo:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  RewriteRule ^es/guarapari/([0-9]+)/([[a-z0-9-]+)/?$ empresas.php?id=$1&nome=$2 [NC]  

  RewriteRule ^es/guarapari\/?$ cidade.php?cidade=100 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Acesso normalmente o endereço: `https://localhost/guiacomercial/es/guarapari/`

Agora quando tento acessar: `https://localhost/guiacomercial/es/guarapari/empresa/1/acabamento` gera o erro 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem um erro:

```python
RewriteRule ^es/guarapari/([0-9]+)/([[a-z0-9-]+)/?$ empresas.php?id=$1&nome=$2 [NC]
#                                   ^
#                                  aqui
```

Deveria ser

```python
RewriteRule ^es/guarapari/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ empresas.php?id=$1&nome=$2 [NC]
```

No entanto, essa regra não corresponde a uma URL com `/empresa` como

```python
https://localhost/guiacomercial/es/guarapari/empresa/1/acabamento
                                            ^^^^^^^^
```

Se quiser aceitar `/empresa` opcionalmente:

```python
RewriteRule ^es/guarapari/(?:empresa/)?([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ empresas.php?id=$1&nome=$2 [NC]
```

**.htaccess:**

```python
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On

  # https://localhost/guiacomercial/es/guarapari/empresa/1/acabamento
  # https://localhost/guiacomercial/es/guarapari/1/acabamento
  #  -> /guiacomercial/empresas.php?id=1&nome=acabamento
  RewriteRule ^es/guarapari/(?:empresa/)?(\d+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ empresas.php?id=$1&nome=$2 [NC,QSA,L]

  # https://localhost/guiacomercial/es/guarapari
  # https://localhost/guiacomercial/es/guarapari/
  #  -> /guiacomercial/cidade.php?cidade=100
  RewriteRule ^es/guarapari/?$ cidade.php?cidade=100 [NC,QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```